# Samba server disappears from the browser list after a period of time

Tags: iptables, openvpn, samba

I have a Ubuntu server running as a router. On the server I use iptables and DHCP 3.1.3, Samba 3.4.7 and OpenVPN 2.1.0 server.

I have problem with Samba server disappears from the VPN client browser list after a period of time (over 20 minutes). The only thing I notice as strange from my iptables log is this:

```
[..] OUTPUT:DROP: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.100.0.1 DST=10.50.0.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58
```

If the VPN client reconnects the Samba server appears instantly in the browser list.

---

### Settings

**Networks**:
LAN and VPN are each in their own sub network. (10.50.0.0 and 10.100.0.0)

**DHCP**:

```
subnet 10.50.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    interface eth0;
    range 10.50.0.2 10.50.0.239;
    default-lease-time 6000;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.50.0.255;
    option routers 10.50.0.1;
    option domain-name-servers XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
    option netbios-name-servers 10.50.0.1;
}

subnet 10.100.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    interface tap0;
    range 10.100.0.2 10.100.0.239;
    default-lease-time 6000;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.100.0.255;
    option netbios-name-servers 10.100.0.1;
}
```

**Iptables (Stateful)**:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.50.0.0/24 -d 10.50.0.255/32 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.50.0.0/24 -d 10.50.0.1/32 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 ! -s 10.50.0.0/24 -d 10.50.0.255/32 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -s 10.100.0.0/24 -d 10.100.0.255/32 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -s 10.100.0.0/24 -d 10.100.0.1/32 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tap0 ! -s 10.100.0.0/24 -d 10.100.0.255/32 -j DROP
```

**LAN**: User are getting gateway, dns, NetBIOS (10.50.0.1) etc. etc. and are forwarded to the internet. (Works 100%)

**OpenVPN server**:

- The server is using tap as interface.
- It does not allow client to client, but have netmask 255.255.255.0.
- IP configuration comes from the DHCP server.
- The VPN client does not get gateway and dns information, but are given NetBIOS (10.100.0.1) and netmask info.
- The VPN connection are not forwarded to the internet.

**OpenVPN client**: The client are using keepalive (`keepalive 10 120`)

**Samba server**:

```
[global]
        server string = [NAME]
        interfaces = 10.50.0.0/24, 10.100.0.0/24
        bind interfaces only = Yes
        security = SHARE
        guest account = smbguest
        syslog = 5
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        name resolve order = wins bcast lmhosts host
        max ttl = 21600
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
        lm announce = Yes
        lm interval = 30
        local master = No
        domain master = No
        dns proxy = No
        wins support = Yes
        invalid users = root
        guest ok = Yes
        hosts allow = 127.0.0.1, 10.50.0.0/24, 10.100.0.0/24
        hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
```